# Import variable from module

Tags: python

I can call function from my created module, but I can't import variable, maybe anyone have any ideas why? 
 Example:

`Module1.py`:

```
a="hi"
```

Python idle:

```
from Module1 import *
Print(a)
```

It doesn't import variable a, but if I call a function from other module it's working

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] and how to create a [mcve] so we can better help you.

Comment: Did you actually use `Print`? it should be `print`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep in mind Python is **not** case insensitive. Built-in functions (or really, *any* function) should always start with a lowercase letter. If your Python file was named "Module1.py", then doing `from module1 import *` would be incorrect also. So the correct form would be:

```
from Module1 import *
print(a)
```

Comment: No its correct module name because how I said I can call function from module

Comment: How are you calling the function? is it `print(a)` or `Print(a)`? the latter would not be valid code